# Problem displaying second level navigation in menu block

Tags: 7, routes, blocks, navigation

I have something strange happening with a drupal 7 site i'm working on. I have a main navigation menu which also provides navigation via a menu block for all second level pages. this works fine - i have an additional main navigation menu which can be toggled with the main navigation at the user's discretion -this is also working fine. however, displaying the second menu in a menu block is proving difficult. i have matched the settings for both menu blocks so they are associated with the correct menus respectively, and yet on the second menu block, it will only display if the top-level links are included. so, if i want to display the second-level only, regardless of setting the maximum depth, nothing shows up. if i include the top-level and set the depth to include children, that works fine; the top level and second level are there. however i need to exclude the top level and this doesn't seem a simple task.

is this a common problem, or has anyone experienced anything similar??

Neil

Comment: ans pls: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100975/menu-image-not-coming

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure if you are using only Drupal standard menu system or any menu modules. If not, check [Menu Block module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block).

This module gives you lot of options to place menu in blocks, including just some parts of a certain menu as I think you want.

For example, you define a block that shows the second-level menu of the current fist-level active item.